# redirect to another page based on the user's role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a feature of my site which is only accessible for premium users.

I want users that are not premium to be redirected to another page to display the positive features of becoming premium.

So far I have this which restricts access to only premium:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="PremiumUser")]
public class EducateController : Controller
{
```

How could I redirect a standard user to another view?

Comment: I would take off the route attribute and move the user role check into the method itself and redirect from there.

Comment: thank you, was hoping there was another way that was built in but sure

Comment: Well, your other option is to build middleware to handle the redirect but this is much much easier.